# Writing dataframe created in Jupyter running on Amazon AWS to local CSV file

Tags: dataframe, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook

I have a data frame created and opened in Jupyter notebook running on Amazon AWS. How can I save it to a local csv file? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to apply the usual `df.to_csv('csv_from_notebook.csv', sep='\t')` in your opened notebook. If you then switch over to the browser tab where the file explorer/notebook list is opened, you will see (maybe after pressing the "refresh notebook list" button) that a new file exists. This file can be downloaded to your local machine.

Hope this helps!